# ScrollView can host only one child

Tags: scrollview

I have multiple linear layouts and I need to add a few more items. Them first layout holds the background image. I'm not sure if that is where it should be but if I put that image into another layout it seems like it gets put on-top of everything else and I can not see the other items. I think I need to wrap the entire layout with something and make it scrollable. I just do not know what. Each time I add the ScrollView to the LinearLayout I get the exception "ScrollView can host only one child..." Code is below.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/dsbackground"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="100" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/custinfo"
        android:layout_width="165dp"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:hint="  Customer Name/Job Name/Job Zip"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:lines="3"
        android:textSize="15dp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/discount"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="37dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:layout_weight="25"
        android:hint="  %"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="100" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="25"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Width"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="25"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Length"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="25"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Eave"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="25"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Pitch"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="100" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/width"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="37dp"
        android:layout_weight="25"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:textStyle="bold" >
    </EditText>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/length"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="37dp"
        android:layout_weight="25"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:textStyle="bold" >
    </EditText>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/eave"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="37dp"
        android:layout_weight="25"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:textStyle="bold" >
    </EditText>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/pitch"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="37dp"
        android:layout_weight="25"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:textStyle="bold" >
    </EditText>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="100" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="58dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="17dp"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:text="ROOF"
        android:textSize="17dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/roofsqft"
        android:layout_width="110dp"
        android:layout_height="37dp"
        android:layout_weight="25.32"
        android:hint="SQFT"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/rooftotal"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="37dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="25.32"
        android:hint="Total" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="100" >

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/Spinnerrvalue"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="37dp"
        android:entries="@array/rvalue"
        android:prompt="@string/rvalue" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinnerfacing"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="37dp"
        android:entries="@array/facing"
        android:prompt="@string/facing" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/roofprice"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="36dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="34.48"
        android:hint="Price"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="100" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="58dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="17dp"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:text="WALL"
        android:textSize="17dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/wallsqft"
        android:layout_width="110dp"
        android:layout_height="37dp"
        android:layout_weight="25.32"
        android:hint="SQFT"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/walltotal"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="37dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="25.32"
        android:hint="Total" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="100" >

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/Spinnerrvalue"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="37dp"
        android:entries="@array/rvalue"
        android:prompt="@string/rvalue" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinnerfacing"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="37dp"
        android:entries="@array/facing"
        android:prompt="@string/facing" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/wallprice"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="36dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="34.48"
        android:hint="Price"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="100" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/roofaddition"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="36dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:hint="Roof Addition"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/walldeduct"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="36dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:hint="Wall Deducts"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="100" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/process"
        android:layout_width="125dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:text="PROCESS" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/total"
        android:layout_width="125dp"
        android:layout_height="43dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="42dp"
        android:hint="      Total    "
        android:inputType="number"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: with many hours of researching, I have figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

try this:
(pseudo code)

```
<LinearLayout 
android:background= "your background"
>
<Scrollview>
<Linear layout>
<Your layout>
</Your layout>
</Linear layout>
</scrollview>
<Linearlayout>
```

if u don't understand, write here